# How to insert null value in a table from a XML?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table which has several columns (`Int`, `Bool`) as `nullable`. I have one stored procedure which is taking `XML` as the input parameter. I'm trying to pass null values of some of these columns, But its inserting 0 instead of null.

```
declare @temp XML;
set @temp = '
<ArrayOfTestFileEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestFileEntity>
    <TestId xsi:nil="true" />
    <MainTestNo xsi:nil="true" />
    <TestCode xsi:nil="true" />
    <TestCode1 />
    <FlgTemp xsi:nil="true" />
  </TestFileEntity>
</ArrayOfTestFileEntity>'


    declare @xmlInput as XML = @temp;
    declare @xmlOutput as XML;

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @insertedTable table(Id int); 

    MERGE INTO Test AS Trg USING (
    SELECT
        d.x.value('TestId[1]', 'int') AS TestId,
        d.x.value('MainTestNo[1]', 'int') AS MainTestNo,
        d.x.value('TestCode[1]', 'int') AS TestCode,
        d.x.value('TestCode1[1]', 'int') AS TestCode1,
        d.x.value('FlgTemp[1]', 'bit') AS FlgTemp

    FROM
        @xmlInput.nodes('/ArrayOfTestFileEntity/TestFileEntity') AS d(x)
    ) AS Src ON Trg.Id = Src.Id
        WHEN Matched THEN
            UPDATE SET
                Trg.TestId = Src.TestId,
                Trg.MainTestNo = Src.MainTestNo,
                Trg.TestCode = Src.TestCode,
                Trg.TestCode1 = Src.TestCode1,
                Trg.FlgTemp = Src.FlgTemp,

            WHEN NOT matched BY TARGET THEN 
                INSERT 
                    ([TestId]
                    ,[MainTestNo]
                    ,[TestCode]
                    ,[TestCode1]
                    ,[FlgTemp])
                VALUES
                    (Src.TestId,
                    Src.MainTestNo,
                    Src.TestCode,
                    Src.TestCode1,
                    Src.FlgTemp)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @insertedTable;

        set @xmlOutput = (SELECT * FROM @insertedTable for XML AUTO, ROOT('RowsUpserted'));
        select @xmlOutput;
END
```

Comment: you want to insert `null` if 0 value found for column TestId and MainTestNo etc. right ?

Comment: My input XML can be wrong, but I don't know how to pass null in xml

Comment: Ok let me clarify - `<TestCode xsi:nil="true" />` for this tag you want `null` right ?? if `xsi:nil="true"` is not present in tag then it should return 0 right ?

Comment: basically I dont know how to insert null value to a nullable column if the tag value is null

Comment: So it might be that <TestCode xsi:nil="true" /> cannot be the correct way to pass null value to a tag. Got my point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use `[not(@xsi:nil = "true")]` when you select value from xml.

So i have applied it in your query. So if you observed the xml you have noticed that i have added value 16 for `<TestCode1>` tag and keep rest of the tag as it is.

```
declare @temp XML;
set @temp = '
<ArrayOfTestFileEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestFileEntity>
    <TestId xsi:nil="true" />
    <MainTestNo xsi:nil="true" />
    <TestCode xsi:nil="true" />
    <TestCode1>16</TestCode1>
    <FlgTemp xsi:nil="true" />
  </TestFileEntity>
</ArrayOfTestFileEntity>'


DECLARE @xmlInput as XML = @temp;

--MERGE INTO Test AS Trg USING (
SELECT
    d.x.value('TestId[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'int') AS TestId,
    d.x.value('MainTestNo[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'int') AS MainTestNo,
    d.x.value('TestCode[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'int') AS TestCode,
    d.x.value('TestCode1[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'int') AS TestCode1,
    d.x.value('FlgTemp[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'bit') AS FlgTemp

FROM
    @xmlInput.nodes('/ArrayOfTestFileEntity/TestFileEntity') AS d(x)
```

Comment: Thanks its working, but whats the use of [not(@xsi:nil = "true")] in d.x.value('TestId[1][not(@xsi:nil = "true")]', 'int') AS TestId

Comment: Yes, it is better explained in this article - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/NULL/71331/.